# CSS Adjacent selector recursivity?

Tags: css

I want to place several lines of text, with an equal separation among them, over one image.

I thought that the using the adjacent selector like this:

```css
.text-box + .text-box{
    margin-top:40px;
}
```

would introduce a 40 px separation between EVERY consecutive `text-box` element, but I found that it only works between the second and first elements, so the third element is placed in the same position as the second one, that is, with a 40px margin from the first element, while I was expecting a 40px margin from the second element, thus a 40+40px margin from the first element.

Is it possible to do it that way?

This is my code:
CSS:

```css
.text-box{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    right: 600px;
    background-color:#404042;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:6px 10px;
}

.text-box + .text-box {
    margin:40px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/image.jpg"></div>
    <div class="text-box">some text</div>
    <div class="text-box">some other text</div>
     <div class="text-box">some other text</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your absolute positionning. Remove it and the margin can be applied.

Demo with the texts over the image (which seems to be the intent) : http://jsfiddle.net/EqXYA/1/

Comment: Nice, but how can I positionate the text over an image without the absolute positioning?

Comment: You can put your 3 text-box in a div which would be absolutely positionned.